# I want to display Terminal output in My gui using customtkinter

Tags: python

So this is my code

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter



customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("system")

def disp_string():
    print("hello world")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.title("my app")
app.geometry("700x700")


button=customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app,text ="Start",command=disp_string)
button.place(relx=0.5,rely =0.5,anchor = tkinter.CENTER)


app.mainloop()
```

I want to display the Terminal output in My gui using customtkinter.

when I run this the gui opens with a simple button, when pressed displays output in my vscode terminal .How do i display that same output in my GUI.

Comment: Use variable and store the text to display on the variable.  Trace the variable and display its content inside the gui

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable.

```py
text_var = tkinter.StringVar(value="")
```

We set the label's `textvariable` to `text_var`

```py
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, textvariable=text_var)
label.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.N)
```

Now, we update the `text_var` every time the button is clicked.

```py
def disp_string():
    global text_var
    output = "hello world"
    print(output)
    # if you want to add the output: text_var.set(text_var.get() + "\n" + output)
    text_var.set(output)
```